# Variation de « celle qui offre un toit aux jeunes de la DPJ devenus sans-abri »

Tags: grammaire, accord, syntaxe, écriture-inclusive

J'ai lu ce [titre](https://www.lapresse.ca/actualites/2022-12-28/acteurs-de-changement/celle-qui-offre-un-toit-aux-jeunes-de-la-dpj-devenus-sans-abri.php) avant d'avoir bu assez de café et j'ai d'abord compris que cette personne était devenue sans-abri :

> Celle qui offre un toit aux jeunes de la DPJ devenus/*devenue sans-abri*.

- Si le participe passé était accordé au féminin (*devenue*), y a-t-il
  un obstacle grammatical/syntaxique à ce qu'il se trouve si éloigné du
  sujet/groupe nominal et aurait-il fallu une virgule ?
- On sait qu'on peut accorder [*sans-abri(s)*](https://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8363364) au pluriel,
  pense-t-on qu'il aurait été souhaitable de le faire dans la phrase
  originale et peut-on l'accorder au féminin dans la phrase que je pensais avoir lue, et comment, et sinon peut-on me rappeller pourquoi ?

Comment: En France, on aurait dit naguère *un toit aux enfants de la DDASS devenus sans-abri(s)* mais la DDASS a disparu, remplacée par des organismes aux noms peu connus.

Answer (score 1):

C'est probablement une erreur d'écriture inclusive si l'antécédent est bien *les jeunes.*  Si l'auteur voulait dire *devenu/e/s* ou *devenu.e.s* ou la ponctuation de ce genre on aurait dû utiliser les trois terminaisons ou même quatre.  Bien probable qu'on voulait écrire *devenus/devenues* sans obstacle mais pour employer de l'écriture inclusive.  C'est n'est pas très facile à écrire ni à lire.

Pour ce qui en est de la syntaxe, le groupe simplifié est [[[jeunes [de la DJP] devenus]] sans-abri].

Après ça il est impossible d'accorder sans-abri avec e au féminin ; c'est invariable. Même la réforme orthographique donne sans-abris aussi mais invariable selon
[Larousse](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/sans-abri/70870). On utilise les jeunes devenus au pluriel avec s (etc) parce c'est un participe passé employé comme adjectif.  Sinon il fallait résoudre le problème qui précède.  Le mot *sans-abri* est déjà au "féminin" dans ***une personne** sans-abri*. *Abri* ne se termine pas avec s comme *logis*, facile à confondre dans ce contexte.